# Malformed access token when getting places from graph api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

When I am trying to get places with long and lat from graph api with following code

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&center="+latitude+","+longitude+"& distance=5000&access_token=.....
```

I am getting

Malformed access token error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting your access_token?

Comment: I am getting it from sharedpreferences but I am using it to send a wall post, it is working perfectly. I am doing following code, but getting that error at my Logcat. 

`facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);  
String stringPlaces=facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&distance=1000&center=37.76,-122.427&access_token="+access_token);
Log.d("Places", stringPlaces);`

Please help

Comment: Edited my code like this,

facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&distance=1000&center=37.76,-122.427");
Now getting this
{"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/search","shares":9}

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it appears that you're passing the access token twice?

It looks like you're initialising the Facebook object with an access token and also manually supplying it in the call to `/search`; many languages will treat duplicated parameters as an array, and won't parse it correctly.

{edit} you're also including the full URL of the request even though the SDK wraps this.
it should proabbly be

```
facebook.request("/search?type=place&distance=1000&ce‌​nter=37.76,-122.427");
```

Comment: Getting this when I try following code
Code
`facebook.request("https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&distance=1000&center=37.76,-122.427");`

Error or smth :)
{"id":"https:\/\/graph.facebook.com\/search","shares":9}

Comment: "error":{"message":"(#100) Distance parameter specified without location","type":"OAuthException","code":100}} now getting this

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct way to pass parameters in the android SDK? I don't use it, but many SDKs offer a way to pass an array of parameters instead of coding them into the request URL - check the 'center' parameter is being passed correctly

Comment: Yeah @Igy is correct you should not add your access token for  places search query .. SO remove it and try.. +1 Nice answer..

Comment: Tried this
facebook.request("/search?type=place&distance=1000&ce‌​nter=37.76,-122.427");
But getting this time this error
"error":{"message":"(#100) Distance parameter specified without location","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}